# QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: account.report_invoice_custom

Tags: odoo, rml

I have received a module written for v7 that I wish to port to v8. There is a report written in RML that I supposed to work on v8 (RML is deprecated but still functional correct?) The report is declared as following:

```
    <report
        auto="False"
        id="account.account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        name="account.report_invoice_custom"
        rml="recreate_customization/report/account_print_invoice.rml"
        string="Invoices"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
        attachment_use="True"
        usage="default"
        />
```

The parser:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class account_invoice(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(account_invoice, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
        })
report_sxw.report_sxw(
    'report.account.report_invoice_custom',
    'account.invoice',
    'recreate_customization/report/account_print_invoice.rml',
    parser=account_invoice
)
```

My problem is that I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/service/server.py", line 280, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 1214, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 1188, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 1355, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 130, in _dispatch
    return self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 100, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 595, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 126, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 613, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 282, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 279, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 732, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 375, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 375, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 64, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=options_data, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 168, in get_pdf
    html = self.get_html(cr, uid, ids, report_name, data=data, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 153, in get_html
    return self.render(cr, uid, [], report.report_name, docargs, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 129, in render
    return view_obj.render(cr, uid, template, values, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1007, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 247, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 187, in get_template
    raise_qweb_exception(QWebTemplateNotFound, message="Loader could not find template %r" % name, template=origin_template)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 185, in get_template
    xml_doc = qwebcontext.loader(name)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1005, in loader
    return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_template

  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 119, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 849, in read_template
    view_id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, xml_id, raise_if_not_found=True)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 925, in xmlid_to_res_id
    return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid, raise_if_not_found)[1]
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 917, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 71, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 907, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: account.report_invoice_custom
File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 117, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/http.py", line 375, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 64, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=options_data, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 168, in get_pdf
    html = self.get_html(cr, uid, ids, report_name, data=data, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 153, in get_html
    return self.render(cr, uid, [], report.report_name, docargs, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 129, in render
    return view_obj.render(cr, uid, template, values, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1007, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 247, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 187, in get_template
    raise_qweb_exception(QWebTemplateNotFound, message="Loader could not find template %r" % name, template=origin_template)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 185, in get_template
    xml_doc = qwebcontext.loader(name)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1005, in loader
    return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_template

  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 119, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 849, in read_template
    view_id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, xml_id, raise_if_not_found=True)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 925, in xmlid_to_res_id
    return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid, raise_if_not_found)[1]
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 917, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 71, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/odoov8/odoo-server-v8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 907, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: account.report_invoice_custom
```

Comment: Feel free to create an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `account.report_invoice_custom` as a `report name`, you need to change without specifying a module name and `id` must be unique.

```
<report
    auto="False"
    id="account.account_invoices"
    model="account.invoice"
    name="report_invoice_custom"
    rml="recreate_customization/report/account_print_invoice.rml"
    string="Invoices"
    attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    attachment_use="True"
    usage="default"
    />
```

Parser:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class account_invoice(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(account_invoice, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
            self.localcontext.update({
                'time': time,
            })

report_sxw.report_sxw(
            'report.report_invoice_custom',
            'account.invoice',
            'addons/recreate_customization/report/account_print_invoice.rml',
            parser=account_invoice
        )
```

Comment: I added the addons in the beginning, dropped my database and tried again. Unfortunately this does not solve my issue.

Comment: Yes. The same exception is thrown

Comment: My  `recreate_customization` module is not in the addons folder but in a different directory which I reference when I launched the server via --addons-path. Could this be an issue ?

Comment: The problem should be in `report.account.report_invoice_custum`.Check my edit.

Comment: Now I get `QWebTemplateNotFound: Invalid template id: u'report_invoice_custom'` I can see from the code that the element `name` on the xml definition of the report should have a dot and on the left side the module and on the right side the name. So that name is invalid

Comment: @GeorgeD `module_name.report_name` is a QWEB syntax.Check my edit it should work (I migrated RML report from V7 to V8).

Comment: You are right about the syntax. But it still does not work, and now that you've mentioned is my exception is of type 'QWebTemplateNotFound' while I never declared that my report is of `Qweb` type. I override the `account.account_invoices` report which is written in qweb in v8. Could this be the issue?

Comment: To override the `account.account_invoices` QWEB report you need to override also QWEB parser.You are right.

Comment: What I mean is if you need to override ``account.account_invoices` you need to override report action and report parser. In your case you create a custum report base on `account.invoice` report so you need a new report `id`.